# Cocoa show app inside another app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nsviewcontroller

I am looking for something similar to this.

I have 1 Cocoa App, it is launcher. 
And I have another App, that is the main application we are working on.

Is that possible to run the 2nd app inside 1st one?

So, for instance I click Run button on Launcher. After I would like to open main application right in window of the launcher. So I have 2 apps in 1 window.

Was looking through internet, and have not found anything related.

Thanks, if somebody can help me.

Comment: It's not possible unless you implement the 2nd app as a plug-in: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/Concepts/Plugins.html

Comment: Thank you Tamas! This answer is what I need to know for sure!

Comment: @PolosatiyVjih  do you have a sample that you created or may be someone else so that i can get a better picture. I also have the same use-case.

Comment: @TamásZahola do you have a sample that you can refer to ?